# Multiple Google Analytic Tags Only Record First Site

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a solution in which I am trying to implement multiple Google Analytics tags, but it only records for one site. This is the cod we are using:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXA-1', 'example.com');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXB-1', {'name': 'newTracker'});  // New tracker.
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for new tracker

</script>
```

We own one of the the GA tracking codes, but not the other. What is weird that if we switch the order, only the top site receives the data and not the bottom. Any thoughts?

Comment: There doesn't look to be anything off about the code. If you see data for one but not the other, presuming that you don't see the data for the code you don't own, then this makes sense as you would need access to the GA account that you don't own.

Comment: We don't own the account but we can access their account. Two separate entities with access to both. This might be a user error.

Comment: :) PEBCAK (problem exists between chair and keyboard)?